# How to traverse up the dom with Jquery

Tags: jquery

If I have this:

```
<h1>or if the title before doesn't exist then this title</h1>
<div>
  <h2>this title</h2>
  <span id="something">
    some other stuff
  </span>
  <span id="this">
    I am here
  </span>
</div>
<h2>Not this title</h2>
```

As I understand `$(':header')` should find headers. What I need it to find the first header upwards from `$('#this')`.

Answer (score 3):

It's hideous, but it's a chunk that works for any level of nesting:

```
var $this = $('#this');

$this.add($this.parents()).map(function() {
  return $(this).prevAll(':header').eq(0);
}).get().pop();
```

Expanded:

```
$this.add(
  $this.parents()        // Adds $this's parents to the current selecor
).map(function() {       // Iterates over the selector
  return $(this)         // Returns each element's
    .prevAll(':header')  // Closest sibling header, vertically
    .eq(0);              // The first one
})
.get()                   // Gets the array from the jQuery object
.pop();                  // Trick for getting the last element
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xtQ2M/5/** (try deleting stuff)

Comment: `.prevAll()` + `.add()` with `parents()`

Comment: sorry... in prototype mode... should be '#this'

Comment: "up" usually refers to traversing the parents. This should work.

Comment: But if the <h2> does not exist, it does not find the <h1> in the parent div

Comment: @Blender ++1 for detailed explanation of traversal

Answer (score 1):

```
var headers = $('#this')
        .prevAll(':header')  // all header within parent of `#this`
        .add($('#this')
                      .parent() // go to parent of `#this`
                       .prev(':header') // got the header out of `#this` parent
          );  // output [h1, h2];
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JXPaM/2/)**

To get `h1`, use `headers[0]`;

To get `h2`, use `headers[1]`;

Also can use

```
$('#this')
         .prevAll(':header')  // all header within parent of `#this`
         .add($('#this')
                        .parent() // go to parent of `#this`
                        .prev(':header') // got the header out of `#this` parent
          ).
          .eq(0); // output: h1, if you use .eq(2) will get h2
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `$(this).closest('h2');` or `$(this).closest('header');` It's hard to tell with your sample code. See [jQuery.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a pretty readable way to do it in case you want to change some part of your logic in the future:

```
var target = $('#this'),
    closestHeader = target.siblings(':header');

while (!closestHeader.length) {
    target = target.parent();
    closestHeader = target.siblings(':header');
}
closestHeader = closestHeader[0];
```

Note: This will get stuck if there are absolutely no headers on the page, so you might want to add a check for that first.

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jNjZB/)

Comment: Unfortunately if there is another parent and the header is a sibbling above that... it will match the 'Not this title' which is down rather than up.